# replace all special character in string javascript....?

Tags: javascript

Why this does not replace ?

code:

```
   var str = "fq$team$456$$$$fq$plrs$4789";
    if(str.indexOf("$$$$")>=0){
        str = str.replace("$$$$","$$");
    }

   // gives fq$team$456$fq$plrs$4789


   // expected output = fq$team$456$$fq$plrs$4789
```

Comment: `$` in regex is end of line. You might have to escape code `$`

Comment: @Pete There is no reg exp in the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), `$$` is supposed to insert a single `$`. This is the result of the `$` character being used to form some special string patterns.

Comment: aka: `str = str.replace("$$$$","$$$$");`

Comment: That seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try `split/join`

```js
var str = "fq$team$456$$$$fq$plrs$4789";
    if(str.indexOf("$$$$")>=0){
        str = str.split("$$$$").join("$$");
    }

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$$` means `$` in the replace parameter. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> $$ Inserts a "$".

Use

```
var str = "fq$team$456$$$$fq$plrs$4789";
if(str.indexOf("$$$$")>=0){
    str = str.replace("$$$$","$$$$");
}
console.log(str); //fq$team$456$$fq$plrs$4789
```